# Best Practices: Should I use ng-switch for this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch

I've got this object in Angular.

```
$scope.columns = {
    workspace: {
        title: "Workspace",
        type: "workspace",
        activities: []
    },
    alerts: {
        title: "Alerts",
        type: "alert",
        activities: []
    },
    main: {
        title: "Main Feed",
        type: "main",
        activities: []
    }
};
```

And in my HTML I need to loop through it to dynamically create a series of columns in my app (think something like Trello)

Each `type` is a reference to a custom directive.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to place my directives.

Based on this data, is the code below an appropriate way to handle dynamically creating these?

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, obj) in columns">

    <div ng-switch on="obj.type">
        <workspace-feed ng-switch-when="workspace" />
        <alert-feed ng-switch-when="alert" />
        <main-feed ng-switch-when="main" />
        <filter-feed ng-switch-when="filter" />
    </div>

</div>
```

I'd love to be able to do something like... `<{{obj.type}}-feed />` but I'm not sure if this is valid, or if there's a better way to create this.

Thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with ngSwitch?

Comment: That looks alright. How different is each feed? Maybe you don't need separate directives for each feed - maybe you can use a single directive which dynamically loads a template based on the column type. It depends on your columns.

Comment: @dsfq - nothing's wrong with it, I'm just looking for the 'best practices' for something like this.

Comment: @Agop - I had no idea I could dynamically load templates. That sounds like exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: could you show use what your directive is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have so far looks fine.

Depending on how different your columns are, you may opt to use just one directive which dynamically loads a template instead of multiple directives. For example, take a look at [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude):

```
<div ng-include="'columns/' + column.type + '.html'"></div>
```